# Omniauth + Devise – How to extract extra properties from facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

This is what I have in the user.rb...

```
def apply_omniauth(auth)
#abort(auth.inspect)
# name, :avatar, :tagline, :bio, :phone, :website, :city, :background, :bioextended, :username
# In previous omniauth, 'user_info' was used in place of 'raw_info'

self.email = auth['extra']['raw_info']['email']
self.name = auth['extra']['raw_info']['name'] if auth['extra']['raw_info']['name'].present?
self.city = auth['extra']['raw_info']['location']['name'] if auth['extra']['raw_info']['location'].present?
self.website = auth['extra']['raw_info']['website'] if auth['extra']['raw_info']['website'].present?
#self.username = auth['extra']['raw_info']['username'].parameterize if auth['extra']['raw_info']['username'].present?
self.username = self.id

if auth['info']['image'].present?
  url = "#{auth['info']['image']}?type=large" #.sub!('square', 'large') 
  self.get_avatar(url)
end

 # Again, saving token is optional. If you haven't created the column in authentications table, this will fail
authentications.build(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'], :token => auth['credentials']['token'])
end

def get_avatar(url)
extname = File.extname(url)
basename = File.basename(url, extname)
file = Tempfile.new([basename, extname])
file.binmode
open(URI.parse(url)) do |data|
  file.write data.read
end
file.rewind
self.avatar = file
end
```

And this is my scope...

```
the_scope = 'email, read_stream, read_friendlists, friends_likes, friends_status, offline_access'
```

It collects the name, email, avatar, and city. But, when I try to get it to collect extra properties such as website and user likes it doesn't retrieve them.

Any ideas on how to retrieve those two properties?

Comment: Try printing the auth object to console: `logger.debug auth.to_json`. That'll let you see everything thats contained within the auth object. Makes debugging a bit easier.

Comment: My preferred way of showing the auth object is with `render text: "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return`. A little more verbose but the results are awesome.